# can deductive system be strongly sound without being sound

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If I've shown that, for a given deductive system, $$\vdash \alpha \Longrightarrow \nvDash \alpha$$ i.e the system isn't sound, can it be strongly sound? or in other words does strong soundness implies soundness?

Comment: The definition of strong soundness that I know obviously implies soundness. Perhaps you could tell us the definitions you are using, to avoid any possible confusion about terminology.

Comment: the definition I was given is "If for every set of propositions, X, $X \vdash \alpha \Longrightarrow X \models \alpha$ then the system is strongly sound"

Comment: That is the definition that I am familiar with: if you take $X = \emptyset$, you get ordinary soundness as a special case.

Comment: By your definition, the answer to my question is no, if a system has strong soundness then it also has ordinary soundness, thus if I have shown that the system isn't sound it cannot be strongly sound

Comment: I actually didn't thought about the empty set, as my definition said "every set of propositions", but now I see that with it I get a contradiction thus the system isn't strongly sound